# pytest_sessionstart in conftest.py not running when conftest.py isn't in main testing directory

Tags: python, pytest

My project structure:

```
cool_project/
   tests/
      cool_dir/
         test_cool.py
         conftest.py

      test_main.py
```

I'm using pytest version 6.2.1, and python 3.8.7. I have a conftest.py, containing pytest_sessionstart. If conftest.py isn't in the root for my testing directory, which is the directory tests, then pytest_sessionstart won't run (for example, if it is in tests/cool_dir). But, if I move conftest.py to the main directory, which is tests, then it works. So how do I make pytest_sessionstart run, when conftest.py isn't in the tests directory? I currently have the code:
tests/cool_dir/conftest.py

```
print("CONFTEST ENTERED")

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print("pytest_sessionstart has been called")
```

tests/cool_dir/test_cool.py

```
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

tests/test_main.py

```
def test_foo():
    assert True
```

"CONFTEST ENTERED" is the only thing that is displayed when I run `pytest -s`

You can test the code on my
[repl.it repl](https://repl.it/@CrazyVideoGamez/Testing-sessionstart-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

I found your question after running into the same issue:   My `conftest.py` file contains both a `pytest_sessionstart` hook and a `pytest_sessionfinish` hook -- and when I run it, only the finish hook seems to get called.

Then I dropped a couple of pairs of `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` statements right in the actual Pytest source files under my virtual env -- one before calling the "start" hooks, and one before calling the "finish" hooks.

What I found was that when the "start" hooks are invoked:  my conftest defined hooks were not yet processed/loaded.   But later, when the "finish" hooks are invoked, my conftest defined hooks ***were*** loaded, found and called.

Looking closer at [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart), the "start" hook is supposed to be called before collection.

##### I do not know the internals of Pytest -- but after seeing that, my guess is...

- If your conftest file happens to live right in the current directory from where you launch it, then Pytest loads it before collection.
- But if your conftest lives deeper in a sub-folder, then it is not found until collection happens, and thus will never be called at "start" hook time.